# How can i limit the drop down list of countries in exposed filter?

Tags: database, views, location

I try to use the script https://drupal.org/node/1772498, but I don't get the right db_query for countries in the nodes. I change the script on these line:

```
$result = db_query("SELECT DISTINCT(l.country) FROM {location} l ORDER BY l.country ASC");
```

and get the error message:

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in DatabaseStatementBase->fetchAllKeyed() (line 2180 of E:\xampp\htdocs\testsite\includes\database\database.inc).
```

It will be great, if somebody can help me!

Answer (score 1):

`fetchAllKeyed` requires a 2-column resultset. You only have 1 column `l.country` in your resultset. I'm infering from your question here ...

- Did you make a views exposed filter ?
- Can you add a relationship to the view on the parent node to filter to the countries set on that node(s)?

Comment: Yes i used a views exposed filter. Interesting idea to use the relationship, but i found only the field Content: Location (field_location) and after add no more other fields. Maybe you can help me with the db_query function from the script. i don`t know where he get the iso variable.

Comment: he gets it from the `LEFT JOIN` ... it is a default database column supplied from the [Countries module](http://www.drupal.org/project/countries). https://drupal.org/files/images/countries-admin.jpg

Comment: @Bruno Have you checked the field in views after adding relationship?

Comment: Ok, my fault! I use the Location module, not the countries module.

Answer (score 0):

I found a nice module collection called views hacks with "Views Selective Exposed Filters". It works very well and limit the list of countries, but now only the short names of countries will be shown.